# box2d's ApplyForce works wrong after cocos2d-x's replaceScene

Tags: box2d, cocos2d-x

i'm practicing making a breakout game, using cocos2d-x 3.x and box2d, referencing [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials).

i create a ball in the scene's init function and apply force.

when ball hits bottom wall, if i touch screen then the game restart current scene.

after restart the scene, the ball's velocity is not same with the first ball's one. it's slower.

i can't find what's wrong in my code. i need help. here are my code, creating a ball and restart scene.

```
void GameScene::CreateBall() {

    // create ball texture
    ball = Sprite::create("ball.png");
    ball->setPosition(Point(100,100));
    ball->setTag(1);
    this->addChild(ball);

    // create ball body
    b2BodyDef ballBodyDef;
    ballBodyDef.type = b2_dynamicBody;
    ballBodyDef.position.Set(100/PTM_RATIO, 100/PTM_RATIO);
    ballBodyDef.userData = ball;
    b2Body *ballBody = _world->CreateBody(&ballBodyDef);

    // create circle shape
    b2CircleShape circle;
    circle.m_radius = 26.0/PTM_RATIO;

    //create shape definition and add to body
    b2FixtureDef ballShapeDef;
    ballShapeDef.shape = &circle;
    ballShapeDef.density = 1.0f;
    ballShapeDef.friction = 0.0f;
    ballShapeDef.restitution = 1.0f;
    _ballFixture = ballBody->CreateFixture(&ballShapeDef);
    b2Vec2 force = b2Vec2(1500,1500);
    ballBody->ApplyForce(force, ballBodyDef.position); // in here apply force 
}

bool GameScene::onTouchBegan(Touch *touch, Event *event) {

    if(gameOver) {
        Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(GameScene::createScene());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: check that the previous box2d world and the previous scene have been destroyed/deallocated properly

Comment: @LearnCocos2D they are destroyed properly.  GameScene::~GameScene() {
    delete _world;
    delete _contactListener;
    _groundBody = NULL;
}  i checked with debug